# Android - How to join two videos

Tags: android, video, join, append

Basically, I am looking for a way to combine two mp4 video files (on the sd card) together.
More like, appending the second video at the end of the first one. 
I have searched a lot, but couldn't find a suitable solution. 
(well I wasn't able to find any solution at all).

So my question is, Is there a library available that can combine (and possibly trim) videos
supported by android?

Most of the java libraries I looked for this were platform dependent,
for ex Xuggler was not much help in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: is your aim to play the resulting thing to the screen? Or write it to a file?

Comment: to write it to a file. well, the scenario is, i have two mp4's on the sd card and i have to combine them together as a single mp4 file.

Comment: Best of probably going with FFMpeg + NDK if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mp4parser library to [append](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/wiki/AppendTracks) videos. The problem is the limited documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use ffmpeg which is providing amazing features to the users to compress, split, merge and all kind of video/ audio editing/compressing/trancoding,etc. Version 1.1 (ffmpeg fire flower) onwards concat demuxer has been added to it, This is working fine in my android application.

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files

Comment: What language is ffmpeg written in? is there a java example?

Comment: ffmpeg is written in C language. You can get example on github like https://github.com/hai046/hai_ffmpeg