# How cut and glue the video?

Tags: android, video

I have three video, I need to glue them together. For example, the first video take 3 seconds later with his second 4,5 seconds and complete all the closing seconds of the third video. How can I cut and glue the video? Perhaps someone faced.
I do not need an application that implements such an opportunity, and tips on how to implement this program, example code.

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154805/android-how-to-join-two-videos/15971076#15971076

Answer (score 0):

Use FFMPEG library it is the best one i ever came across.

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg